# Difference between "Sampling" and "Subsampling"?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, clustering, sampling

I just got this question in my mind, because I have seen so many times in the literature that these two words are being used alternatively, **`Sampling`** and **`Subsampling`**.

What's the main difference between these two words in literature associated with machine learning, specially **clustering** section? Are they actually the same or there are some significant deviations in specific areas?

Regards ...

Answer (score 8):

A **sample** is a portion of the **population**.
A **subsample** is a portion of the **sample**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer brother, but I don't it will work for me as I can find it on google and it's not so helping at least for me. I mean what's the practical difference between these two terms, especially in `clustering`.

Comment: Then what is "subsampling"? Sampling the sample?

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 Exactly; subsampling is simply taking a sample from a sample.

Answer (score 5):

@TinderForMidgets gave the exact definition for **sample** and **subsample**. In clustering practices, some kind of sampling can be implemented to avoid large computations. Usually some of these algorithms require starting points, and again, to reduce computation time, you take a subsample in your sample and assign them as your starting points. So these two perform two different functions in your clustering algorithms. To give completely exhaustive definition:

- Data Set is the entire collection of data to be analyzed. For inferential purposes, this may
  be treated as having been sampled from a population. All of the data set items will be
  classified by the process.
- Supersample is a subset of the data set chosen by simple random sampling. In our examples,
  it is the entire data set, but for larger data sets it will be considerably smaller. All computations
  prior to the final classification are performed on the supersample. For problems
  in moderate dimension (up to 50), the supersample will never need to be larger than
  100,000–1,000,000 points, since the estimation error in a sample of this size is already
  too small to matter.
- Sample is one of several ($R_s$) of size $N_s$ chosen by simple random sampling from the
  supersample. All intensive search operations are conducted in the sample so that the
  supersample is only used for one iteration from the best solution found in the sample.
  The sample size $N_s$ should be chosen to be large enough to reflect the essential structure
  of the data, while being small enough to keep the computations feasible.
- Subsample is one of several ($R_r$) of size $N_r$ chosen by simple random sampling from the
  sample that is used to begin iterations on the sample. This number
  should be very small  because great diversity
  in starting points generates diversity in solutions, and increases the chance of finding the
  best local maximum of the likelihood.

[Source](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1022497517599.pdf)